# The equivalent library for PYTHON of Graphics2d of JAVA

Tags: python

I would like to know what PYTHON library you use to make drawing softwares like paint or GIMP, I have been learning about PYGAME, however at the present, I dont want to make game softwares, I only want to learn a library like graphics2d in JAVA, Should I continue practicing PYGAME to make these kinds of softwares? or PYGAME is only and only to make game softwares. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Searching the web for python GUI frameworks may be more productive than hoping for an answer here. Check e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Comment: I am know the libraries, Cairo, Pango, ReportLab, thank you